# ng-show/ng-hide value is not changing after getting the data from firebase?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

when i am receiving the data from the firebase i am changing the scope of the ng-show/ng-hide value with false.but it not affecting any thing in my view.
the scope value is changing when i clicked again but i have to update the value dynamically .
please help me to sought out this problem.

thanks in advance

### here is my code

```
  <script>
         var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
         app.controller("redeemCtrl", function($scope) {
         $scope.showDiv = true;
       $scope.redeemSubmit = function() {
     firebase.database().ref().once('value', function(snapshot) {
         $scope.user = snapshot.val()
         console.log('Getting Data from fire base' + JSON.stringify($scope.user));
         $scope.showDiv = false;     
      });
    }
 });
</script>
```

### View

```
 <div ng-controller="redeemCtrl">
        <div ng-show="showDiv">
            <form>
                <div>
                    <input ng-model="Coupon" type="text">
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <button  ng-click="redeemSubmit()"  class="btn">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="row" ng-hide="showDiv">
            <h3>{{user}}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just notice **Angular** that a change has made:

```
   console.log('Getting Data from fire base' + JSON.stringify($scope.user));
   $scope.showDiv = false;
   $scope.user = $scope.Coupon;
   $scope.$apply();
```

Answer (score 1):

For custom behavior its good to use ***ngClick*** instead of ***ngSubmit***

Comment: click and submit is not the problem for me it works with both

Comment: setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.$apply(function(){$scope.showDiv = false;});
}, 1000);

Comment: Please try the above snippet(surround your ***$scope.showDive = false*** with setTimeout) or try passing your scope variable as a string ***$scope.showDiv = "false"***

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is not aware of the operations happening in the Firebase SDK, it's something outside its context, so you should notify AngularJS of the changes enclosing your code in a $scope.$apply()

```js
firebase.database().ref().once('value', function(snapshot) {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.user = snapshot.val()
    console.log('Getting Data from fire base' + JSON.stringify($scope.user));
    $scope.showDiv = false;     
  });
});
```